# Put the correct sign in blank space

Tags: real-analysis

Question asked to fill in the blank with correct symbol among ${>,<,\leq,\geq}$.

arctan(x)....$x/(1+x^{2})$ for x> 0. What I did is for x=0 equality is holding and as x goes to $\infty$, left hand side tends to π/2 where right one towards 0. So I made guess that it should be >. So answer was correct but still I am not able to convince myself about my approach as why equality can't hold. Any hint regarding that. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The derivative of $arctan \, x-\frac x {1+x^{2}}$ is $\frac {2x^{2}} {(1+x^{2})^{2}} >0$. Since this function vanishes at $x=0$ it must be $>0$ for all $x >0$.

Answer (score 1):

If a single relation symbol holds for all $x$, then it must hold for a single $x$, such as $x \to \infty$, where the answer is obvious.

Or... just plot the two functions to compare:

[image]